# Python external process not terminating

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an app (using 2.7) that processes requests. When a request of type "A" is received I need to start an external process.

When a request of type "B" is received I need to check and see if that external process has completed or not and then do some stuff depending on if it has or not.

The issue I am running into is that when the external process is done is does not exit, it goes into a zombie state, e.g.:

```
1 Z root     13703 13644  0  80   0 -     0 exit   09:37 ? 00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
```

Initially I was starting the process with Popen like this:

```
DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, "wb")
subprocess.Popen(cmd+args, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, close_fds=True)
```

I tried using os.spawn:

```
os.spawnv(os.P_NOWAIT, 'python', cmd+args)
```

But still the process did not exit.

Anyone know how I can get the external process to terminate when done?

Comment: Give some info about the `external process`.

Comment: Looks like the trouble is with your external process, not the Python program launching it. Does it close itself when done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process becomes a zombie until its parent process reaps it. You can read more information about how/why a process becomes a zombie at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105998/why-process-program-becomes-zombie

For your case, you should first keep a variable for the Popen() object created and then you can call poll() on that object to check when it is done executing. Once you call poll() and if that child process is done executing (i.e., reached zombie state), then the poll() will clean up that child process automatically.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd+args, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, close_fds=True)
```

On receiving request B, you can do

```
p.poll()
```

Which will return either the return code of the process or `None` if it isn't done yet.

More information about different functions you can call on Popen object: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I was not able to save the Popen() object as my persistent storage is a database. But I do save the pid, so I can use that in `os.waitpid()`. Thanks much!